# Recaptcha Enterprise - missing invisible recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

Recaptcha in a paid google account for a site with more than 1,000,000 clicks on Recaptcha (the free quota from google).

there is no option to choose the invisible v2 Recaptcha that is available on the free Recaptcha , only checkbox option or Recaptcha enterprise version (v3).

when trying to use the checkbox version i.e

```
Checkbox ("I'm not a robot") with scoring
```

site key and trying to implement it in size="invisible" i get this text on the recaptcha badge.:

> This site key is not enabled for the invisible captcha.

---

when using the Recaptcha enterprise version i.e

```
Scoring, with no visible challenge to your users
```

It gets rendered ok, but of course don't get any challenges..

any idea how to use the invisible Recaptcha in the paid version?
Seems i pay and get less options than the free version.

Thanks

Comment: I see that you already have two answers for this question, did these answers help you to solve your issue? Could you solve the issue by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You are able to migrate Google Recaptcha V2 invisible to Google Recaptcha Enterprise, as well as create new invisible site keys in Recaptcha Enterprise via cloud shell!

That being said, there are major differences in how V2/V3 and enterprise work, so keep in mind (for web at least) you will need to change some minor frontend and backend code.

Here is the migration guide mentioning the capability to migrate existing invisible site keys:
[https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/migrate-recaptcha#:~:text=reCAPTCHA%20v2%20Invisible](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/migrate-recaptcha#:%7E:text=reCAPTCHA%20v2%20Invisible)

Here is the gcloud sdk reference for creating an invisible site key:
[https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/recaptcha/keys/create#:~:text=low%20scoring%20events-,invisible,-Does%20not%20display](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/recaptcha/keys/create#:%7E:text=low%20scoring%20events-,invisible,-Does%20not%20display)

Answer (score 0):

reCAPTCHA Enterprise and reCAPTCHA v3 are different.

You said on the webpage you are invoking the reCAPTCHA verification [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute) with an attribute data-size='invisible’. Invisible Recaptcha can be used only in reCAPTCHA v2 & v3 and can’t be used in reCAPTCHA Enterprise. Refer [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages-with-checkbox#expandable-1) for sample code of reCAPTCHA Enterprise.

To use Invisible reCAPTCHA in v3 refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#how-can-i-customize-recaptcha-v3).

To migrate from reCAPTCHA (non-Enterprise version) refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/migrate-recaptcha).

reCAPTCHA Enterprise has more features than v2 & v3. Refer to the comparison [table](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/compare-versions).

Comment: > reCAPTCHA Enterprise has more features than v2 & v3.

> Invisible Recaptcha can be used only in reCAPTCHA v2 & v3

wow... looks like recaptcha enterprise has LESS features then

Comment: is it possible to use reCaptcha V3 with an enterprise key? i seem to have no issues but am curious if there is something i may have missed